# Connect c# application with SQL Server mirrors servers

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to be able to make the connection of my desktop application with my mirror servers, this so that when the main SQL server crashes, my application can transparently change the mirror server to the user and continue with the procedures.

Comment: Not meaning that you cannot do so via Code. But, this should be the job of Networks Department. Your C# App should use alias names (like: myAppDB) in connection string, and Server switches should be detected & handled by Network. Basically they remap the same Alias name to point to Mirror DB Then.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do check out the guide for how to ask a good question as currently its hard to determine what you are asking https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Database Mirroring and your web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553920/sql-database-mirroring-and-your-web-application)

Comment: Yes, but I need to do it by code

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do it by code. Just use the mirror alias in your code and your "application can transparently change the mirror server to the user and continue with the procedures"